# How do I get all SQL keywords in Java?

Tags: java, sql, keyword

I need to have a list of all SQL keywords of particular DB engine in my Java program.

I know that I can use DatabaseMetaData.getSQLKeywords() method from JDBC to list all DB specific SQL keywords that are **not** in ANSI:2003

But how I get a list of all ANSI (standard) SQL keywords?

Comment: Just solved the root problem, but question is still opened.

for oracle i'm quering list of key words from:
select * from V$RESERVED_WORDS where reserved='Y' and length > 1 or res_semi='Y' order by keyword;

Comment: Why do you need such a list? Simply put all your identifiers (i.e. non-keywords) in ``, and you can use them, even if they look like keywords.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words might help.

Answer (score 2):

Since the list of ANSI:2003 keywords is not changing, I think you can statically add it to your Application as a list from the following page: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml no need to call the DB for it.

bests

Comment: The link returns 404, FYI.